Реализация движения шара в игре Понг в реальном времени
пишу игру Понг на Си с помощью pdcurses, шарик двигается только тогда когда проходит цикл do-while, в котором проходят все вычисления и отрисовка в консоли, и получается что есть зависимость движения от ввода игрока, и игра в реальном времени превратилась в пошаговый Понг.
Сначала я подумал что нужно использовать многопоточность, но потом прикинул, что во времена изобретения этих игр, многоядерности не было и в помине. Потом наткнулся на реализацию без многопоточности, где можно возвращаться к нужной части кода, через некий маркер. Интересная абстракция, сам не догадался.
short int state = 0;
while(true){
    if (state==0){
        /* code */
    }
    else if (state==1){
        /* code */
    }

Далее написал что в первом if-while проходит движение шарика с использованием usleep для изменения его скорости. Но появилась новая проблема, нет возможности выхода из цикла кроме как опять же использованием getch(), то есть опять же зависимость движения от ввода игрока.
Проблема в том что у меня нет знаний, идей, etc. для реализации движения шарика в реальном времени. Либо искать новый подход, либо найти способ выхода из первого цикла. Смотреть реализацию на Ютубе не хочу, буду решать пока сам не напишу.
Ниже скинул код для того чтобы видеть структуру кода, вся "физика" движения еще не полностью и верно прописана
https://pastebin.com/PV9jeJgD - что было
https://pastebin.com/9eN7tBmt - что есть сейчас.
От идеала далеко, я и не прошу исправлять код, а только дать направление для копания.

"во времена изобретения этих игр" было параллельное программирование в виде обработки прерываний от клавиатуры. Отдельный обработчик "слушал" железо и записывал в глобальные переменные сведения вроде "пользователь нажал стрелку вверх". Основной игровой цикл считывал переменные и отображал изменения в игре.

Интересная справка, идей как реализовать этот подход пока нет. Вообще пока пытаюсь как описал ниже

Ваша проблема в том, что getch() зависает и ждет нажатия клавиши.
Гугл подсказывает, что достаточно перед его вызовом проверять _kbhit():
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
            std::cout << _getch() << '\n'; // Это срабатывает только при нажатии.
        std::cout << "."; // Это выполняется постоянно.
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(16));
    }
}


И снова Здравствуйте!.. Заранее благодарю, чуть позже покопаюсь. Спасибо

Здравствуйте, добрался до своего проекта только сегодня:
1)Отбросил идею с двумя частями кода, где можно прыгать от одной к другой.
2)Допер физику, теперь шарик летает туда куда надо.
Реализовал так, что при срабатывании kbhit, он записывается в int c с помощью getch().  И чтобы уйти от проверки выхода в цикле поставил проверку c==27{break;}, условие do-while теперь просто true, но появилась проблема, перестает запускаться консоль, тупо не отвечает. Уже грешил на usleep, на kbhit. В чем конкретно проблема не допер. Все компилируется, ошибок нет.

Скидываю код https://pastebin.com/NXN8vipD, он не маленький.
Выделю как мне кажется важные, т.к. все остальное работало, и не было затронуто.
А именно начиная с комментария /ЦИКЛЫ САМОГО ДВИЖЕНИЯ/, там происходит движение, всего 4 if, по сути одиннаковые, можно было использовать switch.
После этих ифов уже идет пресловутый kbhit, getch и заключительное условие while
Также заметил, что у вас использован C++, погуглив понял что эти операторы используются без _ в начале.

@АртурНигматуллин Так возьмите дебаггер и посмотрите, где у вас зависает.

Поработал с отладчиком... Консоль curses зависает сразу, подозреваю что она плохо работает с бесконечным циклом while(true), даже операторы паузы(sleep, usleep) не дают ей раздуплиться, и она уходит в бесконечный транс. Как только меняю условие на прежнее, с пошаговым  проходом (c=getch())!=0), то все работает как прежде. Вывод такой что нужно реализовать бесконечный цикл, но без while(true). Может я чего-то не знаю и sleep, usleep не решают проблему с бесконечным затупом, то проблема остается той же, нужно каким-то образом реализовать выполнение части кода в реальном времени.

@АртурНигматуллин Sleep в цикле должен быть один, и его задача - чтобы основной цикл игры выполнялся N раз в секунду. Если вам нужно плавное движение - заводите какие-то счетчики, и постепенно изменяйте их каждый кадр.

операторов этого типа у меня несколько, но все прописаны через if, поэтому вопросов по ним нет. При выполнении кода возникает какая-то неопределенность. С отладчиком легко можно пройтись по коду, все переменные изменяются как положено, но в консоли ничего не выводится, лишь висит знак часов. По поводу крайнего предложения Вы имеете ввиду ввести зависимость кадр ~ счетчик?

@АртурНигматуллин Короче, делайте отдельный вопрос под это, может кто-то поможет.
